# Pass an Array in PowerShell Remote Session

Tags: powershell

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {
param ($first)

Write-Output "The value of `$a is: $first"
} -ArgumentList $a

The value of $a is: @('1','2','3')
```

Hi guys, how can i pass $a as an array in remote session ????.

Comment: I'm not the down voter..

Comment: Thanks @CB. i can't understand why people down vote even if one has a genuine query. i guess stackexchange admins should have a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
Invoke-command -ScriptBlock {param($first) Write-output $first} -argumentlist @(,(1,2,3))

1
2
3
```